# Loading data gives RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast

Tags: open-data-cube

Here is my code

```
import datacube
from datacube.utils.cog import write_cog

dc = datacube.Datacube(app="test_da")
datasets = dc.find_datasets(product="test_da",                       
                            time='2017',
                            )
ds_1 = dc.load(datasets=datasets,
               output_crs="EPSG:4326",
               resolution=(-10, 10))
print(ds_1.isel(time=0))
write_cog(ds_1.isel(time=0).scl, 'test_cog.tif')
```

output:

```
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (latitude: 17, longitude: 36)
Coordinates:
    time         datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01
  * latitude     (latitude) float64 85.0 75.0 65.0 55.0 ... -55.0 -65.0 -75.0
  * longitude    (longitude) float64 -175.0 -165.0 -155.0 ... 155.0 165.0 175.0
    spatial_ref  int32 4326
Data variables:
    scl          (latitude, longitude) uint8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 0
Attributes:
    crs:           EPSG:4326
    grid_mapping:  spatial_ref
```

the test_cog.tif:[image]

There are several columns with no data

And I tried modifying the code in the tools.py:

```
print(xy)
_in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
_out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
```

the xy's output before runtimewarning:

```
[[   14668.76798505 -1709498.906581  ]
 [   14668.76798505 -1709498.906581  ]
 [   14668.76798505 -1709498.906581  ]
 [   14668.76798505 -1709498.906581  ]
 [   14668.76798505 -1709498.906581  ]
 [ -508339.44227333 -1678930.06540269]
 [              nan               nan]
 [ -672261.47159056   246775.00209853]
 [  -97383.21780622   284191.53083551]
 [    8855.54647177   401582.08073047]
 [  126720.75377633   295996.6332109 ]
 [   20481.98949833   178606.08331594]
 [  -97383.21780622   284191.53083551]
 [ -672261.47159056   246775.00209853]
 [              nan               nan]
 [ -508339.44227333 -1678930.06540269]]
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:554: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _in = np.floor(xy.min(axis=0)).astype('int32') - padding
D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\datacube\utils\geometry\tools.py:555: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  _out = np.ceil(xy.max(axis=0)).astype('int32') + padding
```

And my data has some different CRS, Or some of my data has no geometry, does it matter?

Comment: I have the same problem; in my case everything was working fine with `output_crs= "epsg:32633"`, but changing it to 4326 introduces these warnings

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the value of `resolution` doesn't fit the CRS.

From the [documentation of Datacube.load](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/indexed-data/generate/datacube.Datacube.load.html#datacube.Datacube.load):

> **resolution** (*(float,float)*) – A tuple of the spatial resolution of the returned data. Units are in the coordinate space of `output_crs`.

As you've specified `output_crs="EPSG:4326"`, which has degrees as its unit, it means that with `resolution=(-10, 10)` you're specifying a resolution of 10 by 10 *degrees*, i.e. one cell has the size of several European countries. Of course this will cause values that don't make much sense and thus produce warnings in the further computations.

I guess you copied the code and just changed the CRS but not the resolution?